# UiCollectionview Cell unable to change cell size

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have made a collectionview in my interface builder. The cells have one imageview and a label. The problem is that when I run the app, the cells are way too small. I would like two rows of cells taking up about half the screen each. The cells that show up when I run take up 1/3 of the screen combined, and only the top left part of the imageview displays (the label does not show up at all)

I have tried giving the cells and its contents my preferred size in the attribute inspector, and I also tried doing it in the CollectionViewcontroller fil with this method:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 120)
    return cellSize
}
```

Comment: Check the collection view cell in the storyboard that the collectionview cell size to be automatic.

Comment: The cell resizes in the storyboard, but same size when I run the app.

Comment: Can you share your storyboard image and uicollectionview cell constraints? I think the image you are populating in cell has larger size and occupying more space.. set imageview content mode property to aspectfill in dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, Muhammad. I had forgot to put constraints on the content, which seems to have caused the problem!